# Flutter iOS App on the Simulator either boots and does not receive push notifications from FCM or has black screen but receives notifications

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have been trying to get Push Notifications running for my Flutter App using Firebase Cloud Messaging and for the Android App it was no problem.
Now I am trying to correctly set up everything for iOS and I am testing everything on an iOS Simulator: iPhone SE (3rd generation) iOS 17.0

I have tried a few other simulatots as well

What I did so far:

- Request iOS specific permissions ( I do this in a project list, not in any central code )

```
NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
  alert: true,
  badge: true,
  sound: true,
);
```

- Downloaded the GoogleService-Info.plist and moved it into the Runner folder
- Enabled Push Notifications and Background Modes -> Remote Notifications in my Runners Capabilities
- Added the APN Key to Firebase

Now I am stuck at the AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import Firebase
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?
  let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
  var flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(name: "my flutter engine")

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication
                     .LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
      options: authOptions,
      completionHandler: { _, _ in }
    )

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    flutterEngine.run()
    //GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self.flutterEngine)

    // Set the FlutterViewController as the root.
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let flutterViewController = FlutterViewController(engine: flutterEngine, nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    window?.rootViewController = flutterViewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    // [END register_for_notifications]

    return true
  }

  // [START receive_message]
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) async
    -> UIBackgroundFetchResult {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    return UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData
  }

  // [END receive_message]

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }

  // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
  // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
  // the FCM registration token.
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

    // [START set_messaging_delegate]
    Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
      if let error = error {
        print("Error fetching FCM registration token: \(error)")
      } else if let token = token {
        print("FCM registration token: \(token)")
      }
    }
  }
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]

extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
  // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              willPresent notification: UNNotification) async
    -> UNNotificationPresentationOptions {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    // [END_EXCLUDE]

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    return [[.alert, .sound]]
  }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse) async {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    // [END_EXCLUDE]

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
  }
}

// [END ios_10_message_handling]

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
  // [START refresh_token]
  func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
    let dataDict: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(
      name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
      object: nil,
      userInfo: dataDict
    )
    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
  }

  // [END refresh_token]
}
```

In here there is this line:
   `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self.flutterEngine)`
If i leave it like this, the app boots without error, I get a FCM token but if I try to send a message I dont receive it. Not while having the app open or closed.
If I remove it the app boots with error and stays at black screen, I get a FCM token and the device receives the notifications correctly

Here the error:
`Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)`

Is there something I am missing?